# setting Maxmimu lenght for obout Edit control?

Tags: asp.net

In my web application i am using obout Edit control. I want to restrict the user to type only 400 characters how can i restrict the user.i write javascript like this.

function textCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) 
{
 if (field.value.length > maxlimit) 
   {
  alert("Cannot type more than 450 characters"); 
  field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
   }
    else
     {
      cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
       }
  }

// this is text box

but it is giving error like no onkeydown for editor.

Answer (score 0):

on the textbox there is a maxlength attribute that you can see

and that will only allow 400 characters to be entered

Comment: No PaulStack it is not textbox it is working fine on text box but it is not working on obout Edit control